# ResultSet to Excel (*.xlsx) Table Using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to write **ResultSet to Excel (*.xlsx) Table** using Apache Poi.

**Invalid Table Object Error in Office Excel**

However, even though it writes the Excel file without any error, when I try to open it in Office Excel 2013, it shows an error and removes the table object to give only plain data view.

[image: Message while opening file]

[image: Message after removing errors]

**Here is the rough Sample Code [using this example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/CreateTable.java):**

```
public static void writeExcel(ResultSet rs, int sqliteRowCount, String dir) {
    System.out.println("Writing Excel(*.xlsx) File...");
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
    try {
        if (rs != null) {
            // Get ResultSet MetaData
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            // Number of columns
            int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            // Number of rows
            // + 1 for headers
            int numRows = sqliteRowCount + 1;
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

            // Create Excel Table
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Text");
            XSSFTable table = sheet.createTable();
            table.setDisplayName("Test");
            CTTable cttable;
            cttable = table.getCTTable();

            // Style configurations
            CTTableStyleInfo style = cttable.addNewTableStyleInfo();
            style.setName("TableStyleMedium16");
            style.setShowColumnStripes(false);
            style.setShowRowStripes(true);

            // Set Table Span Area
            AreaReference reference = new AreaReference(new CellReference(0, 0), new CellReference(numRows - 1, numColumns - 1));
            cttable.setRef(reference.formatAsString());
            cttable.setId(1);
            cttable.setName("Test");
            cttable.setDisplayName("Test");
            cttable.setTotalsRowCount(numRows);
            cttable.setTotalsRowShown(false);

            // Create Columns
            CTTableColumns columns = cttable.addNewTableColumns();
            columns.setCount(numColumns);

            // Create Column, Row, Cell Objects
            CTTableColumn column;
            XSSFRow row;

            // Add Header and Columns
            XSSFRow headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
                column = columns.addNewTableColumn();
                column.setName("Column" + (i + 1));
                column.setId(i + 1);
                headerRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(rsmd.getColumnLabel(i + 1));
            }

            // Write each row from ResultSet
            int rowNumber = 1;
            while (rs.next()) {
                row = sheet.createRow(rowNumber);
                for (int y = 0; y < numColumns; y++) {
                    row.createCell(y).setCellValue(rs.getString(y + 1));
                }
                rowNumber++;
            }

            // Set AutoFilter
            CTAutoFilter fltr = CTAutoFilter.Factory.newInstance();
            fltr.setRef((new AreaReference(new CellReference(0, 0), new CellReference(numRows - 1, numColumns - 1))).formatAsString());
            cttable.setAutoFilter(fltr);
            // sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf((new AreaReference(new CellReference(0, 0), new CellReference(numRows - 1, numColumns - 1))).formatAsString()));
            // Freeze Pan
            sheet.createFreezePane(0, 1, 0, 2);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("SQL Error while writing Excel file!");
    } finally {
        try {
        // Let's write the excel file now
            if (workbook != null) {
                String excelDir = dir + File.separator + "workbook.xlsx";
                try (final FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(excelDir)) {
                    workbook.write(out);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("IO Error while writing Excel summary file!");
        }
    }
}
```

I know something is wrong with my code, but can't figure it out.
Any idea, why this is happening, where would be potential mistake in my code.

**Update 1:**

Table XML file in Excel archive if created using Apache POI

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table displayName="Test" ref="A1:B881" id="1" name="Test" totalsRowCount="881" xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" totalsRowShown="0"><autoFilter ref="A1:B881"/><tableColumns count="2"><tableColumn name="ID" id="1"/><tableColumn name="Name" id="2"/><tableStyleInfo name="TableStyleMedium2" showColumnStripes="true" showRowStripes="true"/></table>
```

Table XML file in Excel archive if table created manually

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<table xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" id="1" name="Table1" displayName="Table1" ref="A1:B881" totalsRowShown="0"><autoFilter ref="A1:B881"/><tableColumns count="2"><tableColumn id="1" name="ID"/><tableColumn id="2" name="Name"/></tableColumns><tableStyleInfo name="TableStyleLight9" showFirstColumn="0" showLastColumn="0" showRowStripes="1" showColumnStripes="0"/></table>
```

In addition, if I open the Excel archive, it does not have a theme folder in the one created by Apache POI but it is present in the one create manually in Office Excel. Strange.

**Update 2:**
**Sample executable code (Using Netbeans):**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package apachepoi_exceltest;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.util.AreaReference;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFTable;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
    import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTable;
    import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableColumn;
    import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableColumns;
    import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTTableStyleInfo;

    /**
     *
     */
    public class ApachePOI_ExcelTest {

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String outputDir = "Your Local Directory Here";

            // TODO code application logic here
            HashMap<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap<>();

            dataMap.put("ID 1", "Dummy Name 1");
            dataMap.put("ID 2", "Dummy Name 2");
            dataMap.put("ID 3", "Dummy Name 3");
            dataMap.put("ID 4", "Dummy Name 4");

            writeExcel(dataMap, outputDir);

        }

        private static void writeExcel(HashMap<String, String> dataMap, String outputDir) {
            System.out.println("Writing Excel(*.xlsx) Summary File...");
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
            try {

                // Number of columns
                int numColumns = 2; // ID and Name
                // Number of rows
                int numRows = dataMap.size() + 1; // +1 for header

                // Create Workbook
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

                // Create Excel Table
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Summary");
                XSSFTable table = sheet.createTable();
                table.setDisplayName("Test");
                CTTable cttable;
                cttable = table.getCTTable();

                // Style configurations
                CTTableStyleInfo style = cttable.addNewTableStyleInfo();
                style.setName("TableStyleMedium16");
                style.setShowColumnStripes(false);
                style.setShowRowStripes(true);

                // Set Tabel Span Area
                AreaReference reference = new AreaReference(new CellReference(0, 0), new CellReference(numRows - 1, numColumns - 1));
                cttable.setRef(reference.formatAsString());
                cttable.setId(1);
                cttable.setName("Test");
                cttable.setDisplayName("Test");
                cttable.setTotalsRowCount(numRows);
                cttable.setTotalsRowShown(false);

                // Create Columns
                CTTableColumns columns = cttable.addNewTableColumns();
                columns.setCount(numColumns);

                // Create Column, Row, Cell Objects
                CTTableColumn column;
                XSSFRow row;

                // Add ID Header
                column = columns.addNewTableColumn();
                column.setName("Column" + (1));
                column.setId(1);

                // Add Name Header
                column = columns.addNewTableColumn();
                column.setName("Column" + (1));
                column.setId(1);

                // Add Header Row
                XSSFRow headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
                headerRow.createCell(0).setCellValue("ID");
                headerRow.createCell(1).setCellValue("Name");

                int rowNumber = 1;
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : dataMap.entrySet()) {
                    String id = entry.getKey();
                    String name = entry.getValue();
                    row = sheet.createRow(rowNumber);
                    row.createCell(0).setCellValue(id);
                    row.createCell(1).setCellValue(name);
                    rowNumber++;
                }

                // Set Filter (Below three lines code somehow not working in this example, so setting AutoFilter to WorkSheet)
    //             CTAutoFilter fltr = CTAutoFilter.Factory.newInstance();
    //             fltr.setRef((new AreaReference(new CellReference(0, 0), new CellReference(numRows - 1, numColumns - 1))).formatAsString());
    //             cttable.setAutoFilter(fltr);
                sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf((new AreaReference(new CellReference(0, 0), new CellReference(numRows - 1, numColumns - 1))).formatAsString()));

                // Freeze First Row as header Row
                sheet.createFreezePane(0, 1, 0, 2);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error while writing Excel summary file!");
            } finally {
                try {
                    // Lets write the Excel File Now
                    if (workbook != null) {
                        String excelDir = outputDir + File.separator + "workbook.xlsx";
                        try (final FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(excelDir)) {
                            workbook.write(out);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("IO Error while writing Excel summary file!");
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

**Libraries Used:**

ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar

poi-3.11-beta2-20140822.jar

poi-ooxml-3.11-beta2-20140822.jar

xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar

Comment: Did you make sure you're using the latest version of Apache POI? (3.11 beta 2 as of writing)

Comment: @Gagravarr: yes I am using exactly the same version.

Comment: Hmm, pesky... Is Apache POI able to read the file generated without errors? Can it see the table? And how about Open Office - does that tolerate the file + see the table, or does it join Excel in complaining?

Comment: @Gagravarr: whooo, didn't try that. I am on it :-)

Comment: Just tried on Ubuntu with LibreOffice and it worked well, no error message. I can see the data but no Table styles were visible. So it seems there is indeed something wrong with Table.

Comment: Hmm, pesky. Next up. Try creating two files in POI with tables. One with the table but no styling and only one row. Another with all the stylings, and one row. How do they get on in Excel? (That'll tell us if it's the table style that's the issue, or something else)

Comment: Please add a full example so we can try it out.

Comment: @Jens: Unfortunately, I can't add a full example. Because its a really big chunk of code with database connection. But this is the original method code that I am using to write Excel. Exactly as it is.

Comment: @Indigo can you make a minimal executeable example?

Comment: Okay I will try to make a simple program and upload later. Thanks @Jens

Comment: @Jens: Question Updated with Executable code. Please refer to **Update 2**

Comment: @Indigo It looks like this is bug in apache poi. See this [thread](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Create-a-new-Table-into-an-XSSF-sheet-excel-2007-td4288371.html)

Comment: @Jens: yes indeed, if you open the XLSX as archive there is total mismatch of folders and a folder named theme is also missing for a table. So it is maybe Microsoft constantly changing the file format internally or Apache POI needs to adopt with new table formats in office 2010, 2013, etc.

Will see if I can add some comments to the existing thread discussion there. Thanks though.

Comment: i just came here to copy your autfilter row. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with your code is a presence of a single line.
"cttable.setTotalsRowCount(numRows);"
Remove it and everything will work.
If in doubt, compare the XML definitions of some working table created manually in Excel and the definitions created with Apache POI

Answer (score 1):

You have not created your table correctly.
Check:

- Did you create header columns in cttable?
- Did you create the same header columns through cell.setCellValue?
- Remove empty first header column(POI BUG) at the end

  **CTTable().getTableColumns().removeTableColumn(0);**

Put debug into XSSFTable.class, method updateHeaders().

If your table is not created properly, then

```
XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(headerRow);
```

will be NULL in

```
/**
 * Synchronize table headers with cell values in the parent sheet.
 * Headers <em>must</em> be in sync, otherwise Excel will display a
 * "Found unreadable content" message on startup.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void updateHeaders(){
    XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet)getParent();
    CellReference ref = getStartCellReference();
    if(ref == null) return;

    int headerRow = ref.getRow();
    int firstHeaderColumn = ref.getCol();
    XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(headerRow);

    if (row != null && row.getCTRow().validate()) {
        int cellnum = firstHeaderColumn;
        for (CTTableColumn col : getCTTable().getTableColumns().getTableColumnArray()) {
            XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(cellnum);
            if (cell != null) {
                col.setName(cell.getStringCellValue());
            }
            cellnum++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Digging deeply, I found that for some table XML data in the XLSX package, Excel is changing a single `>` to `&gt;` after performing the repair. The XML from POI makes sense (use `<` and `>` to surround XML elements) so I have no idea why Microsoft chooses to break it.

If its the same case for you, I'd not worry too much about it.

If you want to see if you have this particular difference:

1. Create XLSX with POI
2. Repair XLSX with Excel and save to new file
3. Open both files with ZIP editor (e.g. 7Zip)
4. Find xl/tables/table1.xml
5. Export both XML files (POI and Excel-repaired)
6. Diff the files

Comment: Everything should be being escaped when written by Apache POI (it uses a XML library that ought to be doing that). What is the element that you're having to change?

Comment: The instance I investigated involved no changes to the data. It was a read from an Excel-created XLSX file & save to new file action (no other actions performed). POI read in the `&gt;` converting to `>`, but Excel saw that as a bad change.

Comment: Can you post the snippet of xml from before and after, so we can see which xml element it is happening for?

Comment: @EricS.: I can't compare both table simply repairing the file. Because Excel is actually removing this table completely. So it is taking the table as an invalid object. Still I have updated the question with the excel before removing the table.