# How to add table heading drop-down with Apache Poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm generating Excel tables with Apache POI, but my generated tables lack the drop-down menu on each header that appear when I "format as table" in Excel itself.

I'd like to generate this:

[image: Table with menu button]

But instead I get this:

[image: Table without menu button]

I'm following [this blog post](http://thinktibits.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/Excel-Insert-Format-Table-Apache-POI-Example.html), and my code looks like this:

```
        XSSFTable table = sheet.createTable();
        table.setDisplayName("Data");
        CTTable ctTable = table.getCTTable();
        ctTable.setDisplayName("Data");
        ctTable.setId(1L);
        ctTable.setName("DATA");
        CTTableStyleInfo table_style = ctTable.addNewTableStyleInfo();
        table_style.setName("TableStyleMedium9");
        table_style.setShowColumnStripes(false);
        table_style.setShowRowStripes(true);
```

Each column is then created like this:

```
            CTTableColumn column = ctColumns.addNewTableColumn();
            column.setName(headers.get(i));
            column.setId(i + 1);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630507/is-there-a-max-number-items-while-generating-drop-down-list-in-excel-using-apach

Comment: I saw that in searching, but I wasn't aware that the sort menu on a table related to DataValidation - are they linked?

Comment: Check this: http://tiku.io/questions/421420/excel-drop-down-list-using-apache-poi

Comment: I've now tried this, and I can confirm that data validation menus are definitely not the menu I am looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to Alan Hay for the clue - the solution is to add an auto-filter, but this needs to be added as a `CTAutoFilter` for each individual column of the `CTTable`. The working solution looks like this:

```
    CTTableColumns ctColumns = ctTable.addNewTableColumns();
    CTAutoFilter autofilter = ctTable.addNewAutoFilter();
    ctColumns.setCount(table_headers.size());

    for(int i = 0; i < table_headers.size(); i++) {
        CTTableColumn column = ctColumns.addNewTableColumn();
        column.setName(table_headers.get(i));
        column.setId(i + 1);
        CTFilterColumn filter = autofilter.addNewFilterColumn();
        filter.setColId(i + 1);
        filter.setShowButton(true);
    }
```

When auto-sizing columns, it's also necessary to add extra width for the drop down menu:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < table_headers.size(); i++) {
        sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
        // Include width of drop down button
        sheet.setColumnWidth(i, sheet.getColumnWidth(i) + 1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly clear from the example you quoted whether applying the Table styling should create the filter dropdowns for you or not.

However you can explicitly call setAutoFilter() as below to have the filter dropdowns set.

e.g.

```
CellReference start = table.getStartCellReference();
CellReference end= table.getEndCellReference();
sheet.setAutoFilter(new CellRangeAddress(...);
```

Comment: That's really close to working - it generates the correct menus, but Excel reports the output file as corrupted: "Removed Feature: Table from /xl/tables/table1.xml part (Table)"

Comment: It looks like my remaining problem is described by this unsolved question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25570731/resultset-to-excel-xlsx-table-using-apache-poi